# Spring batch partitioning example

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning, remote-process

I am new to Spring Batch. I have a working example of spring batch without remote capability. Though I understood the concepts of remote partitioning and chunking, I didnt find any example which explains step by step. Kindly suggest links or blogs.

I read data from one table, process it and put into another table.

Comment: If you have a question on the subject, please ask it. Asking for links to external sites is off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: What have you tried? What is the question?